# Placeholder doesn't disappear upon focus in Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, placeholder

I have created an input according to the code below.

```
<div>
  <form id="me" runat="server">
  <input id="stuff" type="text" placeholder="Type here" runat="server" />
  </form>
</div>
```

As expected, when i start typing, the placeholder text disappears. That works as supposed to in the Burning Cat browser but not in the Shiny Metal browser. What causes it (styles, server tag, other stuff...)? What can be done about it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firefox and chrome(and safari) act different on HTML5 placeholders. If you want chrome to disappear the placeholders on focus, you can use following script:

```
$('input:text, textarea').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data('placeholder', $this.attr('placeholder'))
         .focus(function(){$this.removeAttr('placeholder');})
         .blur(function(){$this.attr('placeholder', $this.data('placeholder'));});
});
```

Comment: I'd like to deem this behavior as a bug. I mean, if i need to add some JS to make the placeholder disappear, it's got to be called a work-around. Or is there a valid reason why it behaves that way?

Comment: I actually love the Chrome way of doing placeholders. It allows you to use placeholder text as form field labels EVEN if your page loads being focused on one of the fields.

Comment: The selector should be `$('[placeholder]')` because there are many input types which are not text or textarea (email, etc.) and can have placeholder. Also the new jQuery doesn't like (unfortunately) the `:text` selector.

Comment: @xamde: Yeah, I like it too. (Also, The new versions of FF act like Chrome)

Comment: Note that Chrome's (and now Firefox's) behavior is contrary to the WHATWG standard's recommendation: "User agents should present this hint to the user […] when the element's value is the empty string or the control is not focused (or both), e.g. by displaying it inside a blank unfocused control and hiding it otherwise." (http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-placeholder)

Comment: (The W3C spec uses the same text: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-placeholder-attribute)

Answer (score 29):

I came across the same problem today and I came up with a pure-CSS <s>solution</s> hack:

```css
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: +1 for creativity but I need to point out that - while I **really like** the approach - it's not a solution. It's a work-around. I still claim it's a bug in chrome. :)

Comment: I completely DISagree. The text should stay by default, as some would like to use it. If you don't want it, style it away with this SOLUTION, not a hack. It's doing exactly what it was provided to do.

Comment: @dg988 The problem with the placeholder staying when the input is focused, is that it can be confused with pre-filled data. When the placeholder disappears on focus it’s much clearer. I know placeholder should be styled so that it’s clear it is one; but it’s usually not enough.

Comment: You're entitled to your opinion, and having such an opinion, you can style the text away on focus, but don't tell me it shouldn't work in such a way that we both can achieve what we want because you like your way better.

Comment: @dg988 I’m not telling you anything. All I’m saying is using transparent color to hide the placeholder is a hack. A solution would be if I could set display: none, but it doesn’t work. color: transparent means the placeholder is still there but it's “written in transparent ink“. That’s not very semantic.

Comment: I agree that you should be able to apply `display: none`, but my beef was with saying "The problem with the placeholder staying when the input is focused, is..." and suggesting that it shouldn't work the way it does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this placeholder jquery plugin: [placeholderFix](https://github.com/SimonePomata/jquery-placeholderFix).
With this plugin, placeholder tag will work on the same way in all browsers, also in browsers that don't support it.